# Can't create Virtual Switch on Hyper-V, Windows 10 1607

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

On Windows 10, v1607, I am unable to create a virtual switch - it's stuck at "Applying changes..."  There are no error messages.

I tried all the tricks I could think of:

- Uninstall/reinstall Hyper-V
- Do all Windows updates
- `sfc /scannow`
- Checked events log, don't see any error

I'm out of ideas. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Of course right after I post this, I now find the problem.

I had Device Manager open while Hyper-V was trying to create the Virtual Switch. In doing so, it creates a Network Adapter. I saw it being created and right-clicked, selected "update drivers". It then said it couldn't install this hardware and in the Unknown device which I now have it states:

*The installation of this device is forbidden by system policy.* Of course now I remember creating a group policy to prevent installation of network adapters to prevent users to connect portable MiFi devices...